# Adding 1 incrementally to a string with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
  var text = $("#textbox").val();
  var Numbers = text.substring(4, 8); //To get the 4 numbers
  var Num = parseInt(Numbers, 10); //To convert to an integer?
  var Add = +(Num).val() + 1; //Increment 1?
  $("#textbox").val(Add); //Output final value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="next" value="Increment" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="ABC-123" />
```

I have a text box with a string of "ABC-1234" as the value and a button. I'm trying to add 1 to what's entered in the text box every time I click the button. I'm fairly new to programming but this is what I've come up with, which ends with the result of NaN.

Comment: Is there a #Num element you are working with? (e.g. `<input id="Num">`) I can't tell what that part is supposed to be referencing.

Comment: Whoops, let me fix that. Meant to put (Num) referring to the var

Comment: For that matter, you won't want to try `Num.val()` as that will throw an error. That part should be `var Add = Num + 1;`. Then it should work

Comment: try to avoid naming your variables with an upper case letter at the beginning. That's uncommen (see the syntax highlithing here in SO? ;) text is right, but Numbers, Num, Add... write it in lower case :)).

Comment: ... or `Num += 1` or just `Num++` and get rid of `Add` -- also, it ought to be `num` and `numbers` and `add` ... do a little googling for "javascript naming conventions"

Comment: `text.substring(4,8); //To get the 4 numbers` if a user clicks now 8766 times the number is 10000 and you take only 1000 (the first four numbers). remove the 8 and work only with the first argument. It extracts from this position to the end automaticly.

Comment: OR, we help J. Doe43 understand the most basic and immediate programming principles most closely associated with the question, as they stated "I'm fairly new to programming"

Comment: Thanks for giving me stuff to think of! I'll change the vars now. I don't think I'll ever have to deal with any numbers larger than 9999, but I'll remove the 8 anyway, doesn't hurt anything. So far, the changes made it so "ABC-1234" goes to "1235" (missing ABC-). Then when I press Next again, it throws NaN

Comment: If the textbox content will always have the dash preceding the numeric part there is an easy approach, but if it's just _any text_ followed by a numeric part then it requires a different approach. _Requirements Are Everything_.

Comment: There will always be 3 letters before the dash, then 4 numbers after the dash. The letters will change periodically, but only ever be 3 letters

Comment: `replacedText = oldText.replace(/^(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)$/, (unused, pre, num, post) => pre+(Number(num) + 1)+post);` - this will increment the first number in `text`, regardless of it's format ... `abc123` `123abc` `abc123def`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is almost right, but you have to change a few things to make it "right":

1. in dependency of the naming convention of javascript write the variables in lower(Camel)Case.
2. parseInt returns a primitive type of number. There is need for calling val() method on it! There is no function like that. Just use the variable itself
3. you have to prepend your increased number with the letters you chop of at the beginning.

All in all:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    var text = $("#textbox").val();
    var numbers = text.substring(4); //To get all the numbers
    var num = parseInt(numbers, 10); //To convert to an integer?
    num = num + 1; //Increment 1?
    $("#textbox").val(text.substring(0,4)+num); //Output final value
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll make good use of these tips for the future! It's working flawlessly!

Comment: @J.Doe43 if you struggle anywhere or have any questions left... feel free to ask :) Good luck with learning and over all: have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you want to solve is to add one to the numeric part of a mixed alpha-then-numeric text string.

Assuming your text will contain an *alpha part*, then a literal *dash* `-`, and finally a *numeric part*, it is easy to extract the numeric part using the `String.split()` method.

```
var text = $("#textbox").val();
var parts = text.split('-');
```

Now parts[0] is everything to the left of the dash and parts[1] is everything to the right.  Just parse that into a number, add one, and add it back with the rest of the text, placing it back in the field.

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
  var text = $("#textbox").val();
  var parts = text.split('-');     // Get the numbers in parts[1]
  var num = parseInt(parts[1], 10); // Convert to an integer
  num++; //Increment 1?
  $("#textbox").val(parts[0] + '-' + num); //Output final value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="next" value="Increment" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="ABC-123" />
```

This is more flexible than `text.substring(4, 8);` because it will work with any length string and any length number, as long as there is a dash between them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Interesting to see the .split function, never seen that before. Works perfectly as well!